# Laravel 5 Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Cache' not found

Tags: php, caching, laravel

When I use cache on laravel, 5 it keeps on giving me an error **Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Cache' not found**

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class ChannelController extends Controller {

    public function popular()
    {
        Cache::put('test','test value',10);
    }
}
```

It's just a simple cache but still not working. By the way, my config for cache is set to memcached - and it is working fine on laravel 4.2, but not on laravel 5.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Cache is not inside your App namespace, you can either:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use \Cache;
class ChannelController extends Controller {
```

You can then use `Cache` throughout your class. Alternatively you can add a `\` to the existing line you have:

```
\Cache::put('test','test value',10);
```

Answer (score 7):

You just need to import Cache. Add this to the top of your file after the namespace declaration but before your class.

```
use Cache;
```

Comment: It works, thanks :) sorry i have to put the check on the first respond, anyway thanks for the help!